# Veins simulation running very slow

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am running Veins simulation with 25 cars and 100 Rsu's. Simulation is running awfully slow. I tried with the example given and the case is same. What can I do ?
I have tried with Release mode, switching off animations, with command mode, increased number of parallel processes from 1 to 4. Nothing is helping, in express mode it slows down to milliseconds.

Update: Simulation has become more slow when more message are sent and received.
With 5 cars and 50 RSU with Range of 500 meter this is my simulation speed:

`** Event #27359744   t=46.268980990815   Elapsed: 5387.036s (1h 29m)  46% completed
     Speed:     ev/sec=4094.07   simsec/sec=0.00195494   ev/simsec=2.09421e+006
     Messages:  created: 21616816   present: 20679   in FES: 20123`

Currently using command mode.

Comment: are you using the OMNeT++ GUI to run the simulations or the command line environment?

Comment: using command line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out why simulation was slow, events per seconds were `ev/simsec=2.09421e+006`. So I debugged the code and found that for every message RSU receives it sends a message back. So after removing this the simulation is running much faster.